# Transfer Function

Tags: laplace-transform

Vehicle dynamic system (Bicycle model) is given by the following state space model (which also includes Road Bank angle):

$\begin{Bmatrix}\dot{x_1}\\\dot{x_2}\end{Bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}& a_{12}\\ a_{21} &a_{22}\end{bmatrix}.\begin{Bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{Bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}B1\\B2\end{bmatrix}\delta+\begin{bmatrix}E1\\E2\end{bmatrix}\sin(\theta)$

and:

$\begin{Bmatrix}{y_1}\\{y_2}\end{Bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}c_{11}& c_{12}\\ c_{21} &c_{22}\end{bmatrix}.\begin{Bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{Bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}D1\\D2\end{bmatrix}\delta+\begin{bmatrix}E1\\E2\end{bmatrix}\sin(\theta)$

Now i want to evaluate the transfer functions. In its normal form, state space model is given in terms of 4 matrices **A, B, C and D**. How can i proceed further to evaluate transfer functions?Any suggestions, If i were to evaluate a TF between 'disturbances' **E1** and 'Measurement' **Y1**?

Comment: I am guessing you need to linearize around some particular $\theta$?

Comment: Well , I have no apriori knowledge of $\theta$, Infact I am going to estimate it after calculating TF's with Extended Kalman Filter.

Comment: Perhaps you should estimate $\sin \theta$ instead, then the above dynamics are linear?